# How is the complexity of PCA $O(\min(p^3,n^3))$?

Tags: machine-learning, time-complexity, matrices

I've been reading a paper on Sparse PCA, which is:
http://stats.stanford.edu/~imj/WEBLIST/AsYetUnpub/sparse.pdf

And it states that, if you have $n$ data points, each represented with $p$ features, then, the complexity of PCA is $O(\min(p^3,n^3))$.

Can someone please explain how/why?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the number of principal components is min(p,n).

Comment: An answer is here : http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/3220/1316